# import error using tweepy

Tags: python, linux, tweepy

I'm trying to use the import twitter.streaming but it's saying import error.module not found.please I need help as I'm working on a project to retrieve tweets and tweepy is installed on my Linux. I have python 2.7 and 3.4 installed. I would like to use the 3.4. thanks

Comment: If the module is named `tweepy`, isn't that the name you should use when importing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure tweepy is installed if you are using Linux/pip:

```
sudo pip install tweepy
```

Then within the module or class you are designing you will need to import as needed like in the following:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
```

Comment: It should be `from tweepy import StreamListener`

Comment: Both imports should work my last project done with tweepy was set similar to the example from their repo.
[link](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py)